# How to get the ID name of an asp.net web control using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web form that has label controls.  I want to get the label ID names programmatically depending on choices the user makes.  How can I get the label ID name?  The following is a code snippet:

front-end:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSendTo" runat="server" Text="Sendto"></asp:Label>
```

code-behind:

```
foreach (Control c in Page.Controls)
            {
                foreach (Control childc in c.Controls)
                {
                    if (childc is Label)
                    {
                        allLabelValues += ((Label)childc).ID.ToString();
                    }
                }
           }
```

The result is the rendered ID, ct101, which I don't want.  I want the ID name, lblSendTo.

Comment: childc.ClientId is not working?

Comment: Your code behind doesnt run until page postbacks. I highly recommend you to use javascript to collect ID's.

Comment: How does the user chose a Label?

Answer (score 0):

try this out

```
<asp:Label ID="lblSendTo" runat="server" Text="Sendto" ClientIDMode="Static" ></asp:Label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for everyone's responses.  Using ClientID solved my issue.  I also considered using DIVs and looping through the DOM to get the values, but wanted to see if I could get the values I needed with what was already written instead of writing more code.

Comment: There are a couple of these - you may someday need uniqueID - just know it's there for now.